# How to check the non-emptyness of the A-packet of non-split $\operatorname{SO}(2n+1)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms, functoriality

Let $F$ be a number field and $G_n=\operatorname{SO}(2n+1)$ be the split group over $F$. Let $G_n^{\times}$ be a non-split group over $F$.

Let $\tau$ be an irreducible cuspidal automorphic representation of $\operatorname{GL}(2n)$. Then we know that the A-packet of $G_n$ associated to the A-parameter $\tau$ is nonzero.

I am wondering whether A-packet of $G_n^{\times}$ associated to $\tau$ is non-empty?

Any comments are welcome!

(When $n=1$, I think the A-packet is automatically non-empty because $\operatorname{PGL}(2)=\operatorname{SO}(3)$. But I don’t know in the case of general $n$.)

Comment: Do you mean $G_n^\times$ to be a non-split form of $G_n$, as in your title, or literally any non-split group, as your body seems to say?

Comment: @LSpice, oh, I mean non-split inner form of $G_n$.

Comment: This question lacks some crucial details. How exactly are you associating an $A$-packet for $G_n$ to a representation of $GL_n$? Without that detail it is rather hard to give a sensible answer. However, it may be relevant to note that most automorphic representations of $G_1$ will not transfer to $G_1^\times$ (i.e. the Jacquet--Langlands transfer is very far from being surjective).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, thank you for the comment! The way I mean to associate an A-packet of $G_n$ to a representation of $GL(n)$ is by means of so called Arthur’s endoscopic classification. But Arthur didn’t do it for nonsplit group $SO(2n+1)$. But it seems that the same is expected to hold for non-split group 
$G_n^{\times}$ as it is written in (6.1) of the paper https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2018/188-3/p05. So I guess the $A$-packet of $G_n^{\times}$ associated to $\tau$ is also non-empty as $G_n$ is.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, But it seems still strange because, as you said, the Jacquet Langlands correspondence from $G_1^{\times}$ to $G_1$ is usually injective!

Comment: @Andrew Why should the fact that a map is injective constitute evidence for it also being surjective? Besides, I think Arthur associates a packet for SO(2n+1) to an automorphic rep of GL(2n) (satisfying suitable conditions) -- not GL(n).

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, I am very sorry for the typo. The A-paramer for $G_n$ or $G_n^{\times}$ is $GL(2n)$. 
I misunderstood that nonsplit orthogonal group should be non-split at every places. But it seems possible that $G_n^{\times}$ is split at some places and the J-L transfer gives a 1-1 correspondence between some A-packets of $G_n$ and $G_n^{\times}$ both associated to $\tau$. Therefore, the expectation of the same Arthur’s multiplicity formula for $G_n^{\times}$ seems not contradicts to J-L transfer. If there are still misunderstandings, I would appreciate if you correct me!